# JOptionPane in servlet is not working on tomcat

Tags: tomcat, joptionpane

I am using a **JOptionPane** in my servlet as

```
JoptionPane.showMessageDailog(null,"Request is submitted","Done",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
```

to show the user that the request has been submitted. When trying it is working on Netbeans IDE and eclipse IDE but not working when directly deploying war file on tomcat 7.0.32 version server, if Joption does not work how to tackle the situation?

Comment: You should not use JoptionPane in this case. You're application is for the **web**. Use javascript's Alert()

Comment: Do you receive an error message or what do you mean by "not working" when deployed?

Comment: the page is loading and loading after some time it is timedout.. but working fine in IDE

Answer (score 1):

The reason why it's working in the IDE but not directly in the server is because the IDEs have swing components installed. The server doesn't!

However, you should know that even if you make it works in the server, it won't show to the end user, but in the server itself (this is fine for testing on the same machine, but not when the application is deployed). It will also halt the application indefinitely until you dismiss the box.

Joptionpane is for desktop applications made with Swing. Not the web.

Comment: then how to show the user the result of the servlet, any alternative for not using Joptionpane in servlet

Comment: You could redirect to a page that says 'success' or submit through AJAX and then show javascript's alert box. you have a lot of options. The web is your source of inspiration.

Answer (score 0):

You can not use a JOptionPane in a servlet.
All Package javax.swing and java.awt can not be used.

Comment: the how to show the user that the form is stored in database successfully